# Magento Install security patches PATCH XAMPP Windows using Git Shell But Showing Alert after successfully Install

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

Step01. I Download the patch AS Magento-1.9 Version 
    Open PATCH.sh file Line no 67

```
# 5. File pathes
    #CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/ Change to 
    CURRENT_DIR=/d/xampp/htdocs/Magento/
```

Step 02. Open Git Shell

```
CMD> cd .. 
CMD> cd cd xampp\htdocs\magento
CMD>pwd
```

### Path Change as CURRENT_DIR step01

D:\xampp\htdocs\magento

```
CMD> sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh
```

Massage: 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

But Showing Alert "Critical Reminder: Download and install Magento security patches. Download now."

Comment: Check Patch Install or not:
http://magento.com/security-patch
https://shoplift.byte.nl/
The only way you can tell is the append to app/etc/installed.patches.list tells you if the patch had been run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all our stores we have applied both patches and we still receive the notifications.

I believe the notification system does not check if your system has been patched or not, it is just sent out to all, no matter what.

If you have applied the patches and have checked your site is secured using this link: https://shoplift.byte.nl/ you can just mark the notification messages as read and ignore.

Comment: Magento has no ability to check itself to see if the patch was installed. The Magento notification message system is independent, and the warning needs to be marked as read after having taken the appropriate patch action. Magento also now has a [Shoplift Check Page](http://magento.com/security-patch) that includes more info about the patch as well.

Comment: Right, Magento has no ability to check itself

Answer (score 0):

You can check `patch` is installed or not in `Magento` Website by following this link

https://www.magereport.com